# Unable to click button in list item using webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have the following HTML code. **The items in the list are generated in random order** :

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    One
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal0" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Two
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal1" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Three
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal2" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Four
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal3" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Five
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal4" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Six
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal5" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Seven
    <span class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#" data-target-modal="CustomIdForEachModal6" class="btn btn--default btn--s">Send</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to click on the "Send" button that has the text "Five".

I have tried:

```
element = $driver.find_elements(css: 'li').select {|el| el.text == 'Five'}.first
element.click
```

And :

```
$driver.find_element(xpath: /a[contains(text(),'Five').click
```

I have been trying to do this using selenium webdriver, but can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Example :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKd9x.jpg

Comment: Is it some kind of menu list which comes after click on a menu ?

Comment: This is a part of the UL with three LI, I want to click the button corresponding to one of the items in the list  : https://imgur.com/a/GpYss

Comment: @NarendraRajput I have added the example, can you please have another look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xpath` you used is not accurate. Try

```
$driver.find_element(xpath: "//li[contains(text(),'Five')]//a").click
```

You can also try explicit wait to make sure the button exist

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
button = wait.until { driver.find_element(:xpath => "//li[contains(text(),'Five')]//a") }
button.click
```

Comment: I get : Given xpath expression "//li[contains(text(),'Five']//a" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. (Selenium::WebDriver::Er
ror::InvalidSelectorError)

Comment: that resolved the expression error, but now I get a "Unable to locate element" Is this the xpath to the button inside the li ? Shouldn't there be a reference to the button text "Send" ?

Comment: @DeFi312 Is this html inside `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: There are multiple UL on the page could that cause the issue?

Comment: @DeFi312 It could cause an issue of locating the wrong element, not failing to locate anything at all. Did you try the edited answer?

Comment: I get a timeout and then the same : "Unable to locate element"

Comment: any ideas? I am still stuck at this point.. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This worked : $driver.find_element(xpath: "//li[contains(text(),'Five')]//a").click   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `xpath` -

```
.//li[contains(.,'Five')]/span/a[text()='Send']
```

Comment: I get    Unable to locate element: .//li[contains(.,'Five')]/span/a[text()='Send'] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: @DeFi312, Its hard to identify actual problem, one more try if there is spaces in you text `//li[text()[normalize-space() = 'Five']]/span/a[contains(text(),'Send')]` . is it possible for you to share your site url